# Anonymous function content in PHP not working

Tags: php

I've got a website running on a pretty old PHP 5.6.38 installation... and I've now taken the plunge to move it onto the latest XAMPP version (with PHP 8.0.3).

Unsurprisingly, there's a few changes necessary, but the one I can't seem to get sorted is the one relating to the deprecated "create_function" function. I used this to allow me to dynamically sort associative arrays by one or more key names... for example :

```
usort($myarray, create_function('$a,$b', get_usort_function('field2 ASC, field5 ASC')));
```

Now, I've read that I should be using an anonymous function, so have changed the code to be as follows...

```
usort($myarray, function($a,$b) { get_usort_function('field2 ASC, field5 ASC'); } );
```

The get_usort_function is used to create the text required for the comparisons - so for the example above it would return something like...

```
$field2=compare_ints($a['field2'], $b['field2']); if($field2==0){return compare_ints($a['field5'], $b['field5']);}else{return $field2;}
```

Now, in the PHP8 version then the anonymous function isn't working - BUT if I hardcode the string that get_usort_function returns then it DOES work. Am I missing something?

A simplified example of this in action is as follows...

```
<?php

function compare_ints($val1, $val2)
{
    return $val1 <=> $val2;
}

function dynamic_create_usort_function()
{
    $str='return compare_ints($a[' . "'" . 'id' . "'" . '], $b[' . "'" . 'id' . "'" . ']);';
    
    return $str;
}

$a1 = array( 'id' => 9, 'name' => 'Andy');
$a2 = array( 'id' => 5, 'name' => 'Bob');
$a = array($a1, $a2);

$s = dynamic_create_usort_function();

print "\n\n***$s***\n\n";

print_r($a);

usort($a, function($a,$b) { dynamic_create_usort_function(); } );

print_r($a);

usort($a, function($a,$b) { return compare_ints($a['id'], $b['id']); } );

print_r($a);

?>
```

The above example gives output of...

```
***return compare_ints($a['id'], $b['id']);***

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [name] => Andy
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => Bob
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [name] => Andy
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => Bob
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => Bob
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [name] => Andy
        )

)
```

I'd really like to solve this as my website makes a lot of use of this usort function! So, obviously the least amount of rework that'll be needed is the dream...

Thanks in advance,
Darren

Comment: You need to use `eval()` if you want to create code dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue

[`create_function`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) takes two strings, the arguments and body of the function to create. Internally, it uses [`eval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) to create something callable, which is generally frowned upon, as it increases the attack surface area.

From your description, the `get_usort_function` function returns a string; as you noted, if called like:

```
get_usort_function('field2 ASC, field5 ASC')
```

it would return something like:

```
$field2=compare_ints($a['field2'], $b['field2']); if($field2==0){return compare_ints($a['field5'], $b['field5']);}else{return $field2;}
```

You'd noted that hardcoding the string in the callable passed to `usort` works, which I'm imagining is something like:

```
usort($myarray, function($a,$b) { $field2=compare_ints($a['field2'], $b['field2']); if($field2==0){return compare_ints($a['field5'], $b['field5']);}else{return $field2;} } );
```

but a more accurate hardcoding, given the above description of how `get_usort_function` works, would be:

```
usort($myarray, function($a,$b) { "$field2=compare_ints($a['field2'], $b['field2']); if($field2==0){return compare_ints($a['field5'], $b['field5']);}else{return $field2;}" } );
```

When written out like this, it's clear that changing the `usort` invocation from `create_function` to using a callable as you've indicated above won't return anything (so `usort` will leave all the elements in their existing order). This may be the part that wasn't clear in your understanding of how it was working.

#### Solution

You could do something like the following (which may be similar to a simplified version of the internal logic of the existing `get_usort_function`):

```
<?php

function print_people($people) {
  foreach($people as ['id' => $id, 'name' => $name]) {
    print("{$id}: {$name}\n");
  }
  print("\n");
}

function get_usort_callable(...$fields) {
  return function ($a, $b) use ($fields) {
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
      $result = $a[$field] <=> $b[$field];
      if ($result != 0) { return $result; }
    }
    return 0;
  };
}

$a1 = ['id' => 9, 'name' => 'Andy'];
$a2 = ['id' => 6, 'name' => 'Carol'];
$a3 = ['id' => 5, 'name' => 'Bob'];
$a = [$a1, $a2, $a3];

print_people($a);

usort($a, get_usort_callable('id', 'name'));

print_people($a);

usort($a, get_usort_callable('name', 'id'));

print_people($a);
```

which gives the following output:

```
9: Andy
6: Carol
5: Bob

5: Bob
6: Carol
9: Andy

9: Andy
5: Bob
6: Carol
```

The main takeaway here is using the `use` keyword on the anonymous function returned by `get_usort_callable` to make `$fields` available for use. If you wanted to match the functionality of the existing `get_usort_function` you could rewrite it to take a `string`, and split that up.

#### Minimal work

Given that you are going to have to move away from `create_function` to use PHP 8, the least amount of work you can do will be to rewrite `get_usort_function` to return a callable (similar to above) and replace invocations like:

```
usort($myarray, create_function('$a,$b', get_usort_function(...)));
```

with:

```
usort($myarray, get_usort_function(...));
```

Given that you have access to the internal logic of `get_usort_function` it should not be *too* difficult, and thankfully that is only in one spot. The refactoring of the call-sites is pretty mechanical too, almost a find and replace with any IDE.

Going forward (and depending on your preference), you may want to replace the SQL `ORDER BY` style string with a structured array, eg:

```
'field2 ASC, field5 ASC'
```

becomes:

```
[
  [
    'field' => 'field2',
    'direction' => 'asc'
  ],
  [
    'field' => 'field5',
    'direction' => 'asc'
  ]
]
```

to avoid possible issues with whitespacing etc that require additional handling in `get_usort_function`.

#### `create_function` vs anonymous functions

When moving from uses of `create_function` to using anonymous functions, you no longer need to have the arguments and body of the function passed as strings. For example, the following two callables are equivalent:

```
create_function('$a,$b', 'return $a["id"] <=> $b["id"];')
```

```
function($a, $b) { return $a["id"] <=> $b["id"]; }
```

and could be used interchangeably.

Adding in one level of indirection (as you have in your question), through use of the following functions:

```
function sort_by_function_body($field) {
  return "return \$a[\"{$field}\"] <=> \$b[\"{$field}\"];";
}

function sort_by_callable($field) {
  return function($a, $b) use ($field) { return $a[$field] <=> $b[$field]; };
}
```

these two are also equivalent:

```
create_function('$a,$b', sort_by_function_body('id'))
```

```
sort_by_callable('id')
```

The main takeaway from this is that the `sort_by_callable` function itself returns a specialised anonymous function, which will sort on the field passed in, as opposed to a string containing the code to perform the same logic.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!

I've taken what you've said and reworked things to get a working solution that I need...

```
$a1 = array( 'id' => 7, 'name' => 'Andy', 'dob' => '01-02-2020');
$a2 = array( 'id' => 7, 'name' => 'Bob', 'dob' => '01-02-2022');
$a3 = array( 'id' => 9, 'name' => 'Guy', 'dob' => '01-02-2021');
$a4 = array( 'id' => 7, 'name' => 'Mick', 'dob' => '01-02-2023');
$a5 = array( 'id' => 3, 'name' => 'Daz', 'dob' => '01-02-2019');
$a6 = array( 'id' => 7, 'name' => 'Daz', 'dob' => '01-02-2021');

$a = array($a1, $a2, $a3, $a4, $a5, $a6);

function get_usort_function_callable($order_bys, $mode = 1)
{
    return function ($a, $b) use ($order_bys, $mode)
    {
        // We get the options in reverse order, so we can properly nest them.
        $order_by_options_r = array_reverse(explode(",", $order_bys));
        #print_r($order_by_options_r);
        #print "MODE = $mode";

        $first_element = TRUE;
        
        foreach ($order_by_options_r as $order_by)
        {
            if (( isset($retval) ) AND ( strlen($retval) > 0 ))
            {
                $inner_val = $retval;
            }

            $order_by = trim($order_by);
            $indexOfSpace = strpos($order_by, " ");

            if( $indexOfSpace !== FALSE )
            {
                $column = trim(substr($order_by,0,$indexOfSpace));
                $sortorder = trim(substr($order_by,$indexOfSpace));

                if ( strcasecmp($sortorder,"DESC") == 0 )
                {
                    switch ( $mode )
                    {
                        case 1:
                        case 2:
                            $comp = '$b[' . "'" . $column . "'" . '] <=> $a[' . "'" . $column . "'" . ']';
                        break;
                        case 3:
                            $comp = 'strtotime($b[' . "'" . $column . "'" . ']) <=> strtotime($a[' . "'" . $column . "'" . '])';
                        break;
                        case 4:
                            $comp = 'strnatcmp($b[' . "'" . $column . "'" . '], $a[' . "'" . $column . "'" . '])';
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    switch ( $mode )
                    {
                        case 1:
                        case 2:
                            $comp = '$a[' . "'" . $column . "'" . '] <=> $b[' . "'" . $column . "'" . ']';
                        break;
                        case 3:
                            $comp = 'strtotime($a[' . "'" . $column . "'" . ']) <=> strtotime($b[' . "'" . $column . "'" . '])';
                        break;
                        case 4:
                            $comp = 'strnatcmp($a[' . "'" . $column . "'" . '], $b[' . "'" . $column . "'" . '])';
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if($first_element)
                {
                    $retval = 'return ' . $comp . ';';
                    $first_element = FALSE;
                } else {
                    $retval = '$' . $column . '=' . $comp . '; if ( $' . $column . ' == 0 ) { ' . $inner_val . ' } else { return $' . $column . '; }';
                }
            }
        }

        #print "RET = $retval\n";

        return eval($retval);
    };
}

usort($a, get_usort_function_callable("dob ASC, id DESC, name DESC") );

print_r($a);
```

This works pretty much exactly as I need it now, with the spaceship operator allowing me to get rid of the extra "helper" functions (i.e. compare_dates, compare_ints) and the final eval (of the string that was produced) meaning that the function is returned rather than a string of the function.

Whether I should really be using eval() I'm not sure - prob not, but given that the content of the function is dynamic (i.e. due to the fields being sorted by being dynamic) then I think it's maybe justified.

Now I just need to rework the code slightly, so that all of these calls...

```
usort($wishlist_details, create_function('$a,$b', get_usort_function('wishlistcountryname ASC, wishlistname ASC')));
```

...become calls like this...

```
usort($_wishlist_details, get_usort_function_callable('wishlistcountryname ASC, wishlistname ASC') );
```

Better get my regex skills sorted for a global search/replace rather than manually editing each file!

Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: I've added some more information to my answer, to keep it a bit cleaner, but the main thing that needs to be changed in your current `get_usort_function_callable` function is that it should not return a function that returns a string of the PHP code to execute, it should return a function that _is_ that code, for lack of a better term. Also, the way that `usort` and similar function operate is to run the callable to compare two elements in the array, and use that for sorting, so it will be called many times for a given array.

Comment: I've just updated my answer (which was really a reply) with the final working solution. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: All good. Seems like it has been cleaned up a bit as part of the refactor, which is always what you want when you touch code; to make it a bit better than when you found it :) You _should_ look to remove the `eval` at some point, but that can be a job for a later date. Your use here isn't too bad, as the string it's evaluating is only based in fixed input (ie nothing from the user), but you may also find better performance from a straight code solution.